# It delivers PropertyNotFoundException Primefaces pieModel and JSFBeans

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listener, javabeans, propertynotfoundexception

```
 <f:event type="preRenderView"
                listener="#{fewosByRegionBean.getFewosByRegion().pieModel}"/>
        </f:metadata>
<p:chart id="pie" type="pie" model="#{fewosByRegionBean.getFewosByRegion().pieModel}" responsive="true" />
```

It delivers the PropertyNotfoundexception, but i dont understand why since i have getter and setter

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/protected/search2.xhtml @23,67 listener="#{fewosByRegionBean.getFewosByRegion().pieModel}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null`

Comment: There are about 1.000.000 duplicates of this. Did you read them? And if something is null, you cannot read a property on it

Comment: yes i did, but id dont understand in which order i need to put ..Bean, getFewosByRegion() and pieModel

Comment: Uhhhmmm.... but that is **your** code